# Font's size of the axes labels in PDF will be smaller?

Tags: graphics, fonts

In Mathematica 13.2, I set the font size of the axes labels to be 14, but after exporting it, in PDF format, I see that the font size is 10.10. What is the reason and how should I fix the font size in the PDF format file.

For example:

```
a=Plot[Sin[x], {x, 5, 10}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 14]];
Export["C:\\Users\\PC\\Downloads\\22.pdf", a]
```

The font size of the labels should be 14, but in the PDF file, it is 10.10:
[image: Font size changed.]

If I copied the figure in Mathematica and pasted it into MS Word, and then save the Word file to PDF. The ticks' font size is 14. So, converting the figure to PDF by Mathematica causes the font size changed.

`CouldExport` could cause the same problem.

> CloudExport[a, "pdf"]

Comment: You used the wrong option. You need `TicksStyle->Directive[{[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 14}]`. This fixes the size of the figures at the axes. Try and inform us, if it helps.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch  Try it and you will get the same result.

Comment: I did, and got what I expected. If you do not, then the problem is in the step of converting your material to pdf. In general, I do not know how to solve the conversion problem. However, I would first try to rasterize the image before conversion. This may help.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch  I updated my question. May you check that if ours' code is the same?

Comment: Exporting to PDF is like printing, so it uses the Printing environment.  That environment sets a non-standard Magnification setting.  There isn't a really easy way to alter it when calling Export on something other than a notebook.

Comment: Why did you say that is uses the Printing environment and sets a non-standard Magnification setting? Where can I check this? @ihojnicki

Comment: That is how it's implemented.  10.10 / 14. = .72xxxx.  The Printout style in the Default stylesheet sets Magnification->0.72.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole graphic is being set to `Magnification->.72` as a result of using the Printout stylesheet environment.  So, it's not just the tick labels, but everything is being scaled by a factor of .72.  You could set the font size directly to accommodate, but doing so would cause the graphic as a whole to look different since the fonts would be a different relative size to the graphic as a whole.  So the best thing to do is to fix the magnification at the level of the entire graphic.  This can be done by adding `BaseStyle->{Magnification->1}` as an option to the functions generating the graphics.  E.g.,

```
a=Plot[Sin[x], {x, 5, 10}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 14],
 BaseStyle->{Magnification->1}];
Export["C:\\Users\\PC\\Downloads\\22.pdf", a]
```

Comment: Thanks. May you tell me why the default magnification is 0.72 and where do you know this? How did you know that? As `Options[Plot]` doesn't contain `Magnification` specifier.

Comment: PDF export uses the default printing environment, which is generally "Printout".  Default.nb has the following definition for the "Printout" environment: `Cell[StyleData[All, "Printout"], Magnification->0.72]`.  What my example does isn't to override a `Plot` default...it's overriding a default inherited from the stylesheet of the notebook that's displaying the result.

Comment: I can find the file `Default_8.0.nb`, but how I can't find `Cell[StyleData[All, "Printout"], Magnification->0.72]`. Where is it? Thanks.

Comment: It's in SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Stylesheets/Default.nb.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the `TicksStyle`, rather than `LabelStyle`, as I have already once explained.
Compare two plots:

```
a = Column[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 5, 10}, 
    TicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 12], 
    ImageSize -> 300],
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 5, 10}, 
    TicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", 16], 
    ImageSize -> 300]
   }]
Export["C:\Users\PC\Downloads\22.pdf", a]
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks. But in the output PDF, their font size is 8.65 and 11.50.